# Error Message is Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I typed in these two commands to my terminal and they were working

> pip install smbus-cffi

> pip install git+https://github.com/bivab/smbus-cffi.git

There is python and git on the raspberry pi. I'm following this tutorial as a guide to download the smbus-cffi. When I press "python setup.py install," the error message is "can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory." Why cant it open the file?

I tried upgrading the setup tools and then ran the "python setup.py," but it still doesn't work. My assumption is that I'm on the incorrect file path that's why the command doesn't run. How do I find the correct file path?

If something is downloaded on the root folder of rpi, can it still be accessed when I go out of the root? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're in the correct directory?

I would recommend the following set of commands as an alternative

```
git clone https://github.com/bivab/smbus-cffi

cd smbus-cffi

python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much for answering my question. I genuinely appreciate that, It worked out for me. Thank you!